# PHP convert array of unique items into complex like query strings

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php array containing data in the below format. There may only ever be unique values and **one NULL value**, which needs negative like matches for the other values.

```
$colors = array_unique([
    NULL,
    "red",
    "black"
]);
```

I want to convert it into the following:

```
$converted = [
    "NOT LIKE '%red%' AND NOT LIKE '%black%'",
    "LIKE '%red%' AND NOT LIKE '%black%'",
    "LIKE '%black%' AND NOT LIKE '%red%'"
];
```

How can I achieve this?

I cannot get my head around how to accomplish this in php, I've tried different combinations of foreach loops with arrays but I cannot do it dynamically so that the first `$colour` array can expand in values but it keeps the same principle (see example 2 of expanded data in same structure).

*Example 2*

```
$colors = array_unique([
    NULL,
    "red",
    "black",
    "purple",
    "orange"
]);
```

```
$converted = [
    "NOT LIKE '%red%' AND NOT LIKE '%black%' AND NOT LIKE '%purple%' AND NOT LIKE '%orange%'",
    "LIKE '%red%' AND NOT LIKE '%black%' AND NOT LIKE '%purple%' AND NOT LIKE '%orange%'",
    "LIKE '%black%' AND NOT LIKE '%purple%' AND NOT LIKE '%orange%' AND NOT LIKE '%red%'",
    "LIKE '%purple%' AND NOT LIKE '%orange%' AND NOT LIKE '%red%' AND NOT LIKE '%black%'",
    "LIKE '%orange%' AND NOT LIKE '%red%' AND NOT LIKE '%black%' AND NOT LIKE '%purple%'",
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here ye go

```
    <?php

function my_array_unique_query($values){
   $copy = $values;
    $query = array();

  foreach($values as $a){
      $copy = remove_null_and_like($values, $a);
      $q = "";
      if(!empty($a) && !is_null($a)){
          $q .= "LIKE %".$a."%'";
      }else{
          $q .= "NOT LIKE ".array_pop($copy);
      }
      if(count($copy) > 0){
          $q .= "AND NOT LIKE '".implode(' AND NOT LIKE ', $copy);
      }

      $query[] = $q;
  }
  return $query;
}

function remove_null_and_like($values, $like){
    $return = array();
    foreach($values as $a){
        if(!empty($a) && !is_null($a) && $a != $like){
            $return[] = "%".$a."%";
        }
    }
    return $return;
}

print_r(my_array_unique_query([
    NULL,
    "red",
    "black"
]));

print_r(my_array_unique_query([
    NULL,
    "red",
    "black",
    "purple",
    "orange"
]));

print_r(my_array_unique_query([
    NULL,
    "red"
]));
```

Comment: That works but it breaks if there's only two values `[NULL, 'red']` for example?